# R rolling up rows to a single row (continuous & factor variables)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to roll up a bunch of rows for one day into a single row. I would like it in dplyr if possible. I know that my code is far from correct, but this was how far I got:

```
data %>%
  group_by(DAY) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(Sum = n()), SEX, GROUP, TOTAL)
```

Original:

```
DAY SEX GROUP   TOTAL       
7/1/14  FEMALE  A   1       
7/1/14  FEMALE  B   1       
7/1/14  FEMALE  B   1       
7/1/14  FEMALE  A   1       
7/1/14  MALE    A   1       
7/1/14  MALE    B   2
```

New:

```
DAY     FEMALE  MALE    GROUP_A GROUP_B TOTAL
7/1/14  4       2       3       3       7
```

Comment: Well, at first glance, the easiest would be to write it out `data %>% group_by(DAY) %>% summarise(FEMALE = sum(SEX == "FEMALE"), MALE = sum(SEX == "MALE"), GROUP_A = sum(GROUP == "A"), GROUP_B = sum(GROUP == "B"), TOTAL = sum(TOTAL))`. But I guess you are striving for code elegance. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way with `data.table`, tested on a `data.frame` with more than one day.

```
require(data.table)
setDT(data)[, as.list(c(table(SEX), table(GROUP), TOTAL=sum(TOTAL))), by=DAY]

#      DAY FEMALE MALE A B TOTAL
#1: 7/1/14      3    0 1 2     3
#2: 8/1/14      1    2 2 1     4
```

***EDIT: another, less manual, option (you don't need to know which variables are factors and which are numeric), thanks to some help from @jangorecki and @DavidArenburg***

```
wh_num <- sapply(data, is.numeric)[-1]
wh_fact <-sapply(data, is.factor)[-1]
setDT(data)[, as.list(c(lapply(.SD[, wh_fact, with = FALSE], table), 
                        lapply(.SD[, wh_num, with = FALSE], sum), 
                        recursive = TRUE)), by = DAY]

#      DAY SEX.FEMALE SEX.MALE GROUP.A GROUP.B TOTAL
#1: 7/1/14          3        0       1       2     3
#2: 8/1/14          1        2       2       1     4
```

**data**

```
data <- structure(list(DAY = c("7/1/14", "7/1/14", "7/1/14", "8/1/14", 
"8/1/14", "8/1/14"), SEX = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("FEMALE", "MALE"), class = "factor"), GROUP = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
    TOTAL = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("DAY", "SEX", 
"GROUP", "TOTAL"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 5):

It may seem a little arcane, but here is a short incantation

```
dat %>% group_by(DAY) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(ifelse(is.numeric(.), sum(.), list(table(.))))) -> res

data.frame(DAY=res$DAY, t(unlist(res[, 2:ncol(res)])))
#      DAY SEX.FEMALE SEX.MALE GROUP.A GROUP.B TOTAL
# 1 7/1/14          4        2       3       3     7
```

Here, you simply summarise each column as a table if it's not numeric, or sum it if it is (for the total column).  This needs to be returned as a list since `summarise_each` expects a single value.  Then, the result is expanded to a regular `data.frame`.

Comment: I'm not sure it works correctly for several dates though. For example if you''ll change the last 3 dates to `8/1/14`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg yea, it's for the special case of a single row.  You could make it work for more, something along the lines of unlist and rbind the rows together I guess.

Comment: if there are more than 1 day (which is very likely to happen), this will work to reformat the results : `data.frame(DAY=res$DAY, t(apply(res[, 2:ncol(res)], 1, unlist)))`

Answer (score 3):

The way you calculate the total (sum) and the other columns (table) differ substantially, so you probably have to do these steps seperately. Calculating the total is easy. For the tabulation, I suggest using `tidyr` as follows:

```
# required packages
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

# calculations
data %>%
  group_by(DAY) %>%                     # group by day
  mutate(TOTAL = sum(TOTAL)) %>%        # first calculate total
  gather(key, value, -DAY, -TOTAL) %>%  # collapse
  unite(group, key, value) %>%          # get sensible column names
  group_by(DAY, TOTAL) %>%              # group by day and total
  do(as.data.frame(table(.$group))) %>% # table
  spread(Var1, Freq)                    # spread out

##      DAY TOTAL GROUP_A GROUP_B SEX_FEMALE SEX_MALE
## 1 7/1/14     7       3       3          4        2
```

Comment: I'm truly surprised you preferred this over complicated `dplyr/tidyr` solution over a simple `data.table` solution which you posted many times before.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: I usually try to answer with the packages the OP seems to prefer. But I agree that in this case the data.table solution is preferable (and I have upvoted it).

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach:

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)

cbind(dcast(df, DAY~SEX), 
      dcast(df, DAY~GROUP)[-1], 
      setDT(df)[,.(total=sum(TOTAL)),DAY][,-1,with=F])

#     DAY FEMALE MALE A B total
#1 7/1/14      4    2 3 3     7
```